# I have a SQL table with one float column populated with values like these:

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with one float column populated with values like these:

0.0000
0.2100
0.0000
5.0000
0.0000
30.9100
148.4700
0.0000

I need a query to fetch data between '0.0000' to '5.0000'.

I have tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM table where colmn  
>='0.0000'
<='5.0000';
```

But this gives the details which the amount is more than '5.000'.

Comment: That looks as if your intention is to have two separate `And` or `Or` expressions, e.g. `where column1  >='0.0000' And column2 <='5.0000'`

Comment: Do you really want string constants like _'5.0000'_ or rather numeric ones like _5.0000_?

Comment: i tried between function aswell but no luck

Comment: For SQL questions it usually makes sense to Edit your Question and _"Tag your RDBMS"_ as well as _"creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example"_ as a `Create Table` statement plus a few `Insert Into` lines plus a description of the expected result. That way the readers would learn all the required info to help you to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: See also https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14 and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any connection to apostrophe-cms. You should remove the CMS tags since you are asking a general SQL question, and add a clarification of which SQL database you are using, as well as showing the table definition for at least this one column (in MySQL that would be "show create table tablename").

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

`select * from tab where col >= 0.0 and col <= 5.0`

or

`select * from tab where col between 0.0 and 5.0`